# Tool to ssh to multiple servers by giving list of servers

Tags: ssh

Is there a tool you prefer to use which given a list of hosts can open windows/panes to all those hosts and provide synchronized typing across all of them?
I'm aware of tmux (it can't start from a list of servers) and csshx

Comment: I use both/either of those for that exact operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you own a Mac computer you can use iTerm to do that, by opening all windows in advance and then type: `Cmd + Shift + I`.

Or you can use Ansible ad-hoc commands:

Just install Ansible on your "management" box, exchange ssh-keys between this box and all your target machines and you can send a command to all machines with just one "Enter".